# websocket sending messages issue

Tags: javascript, websocket

The following code below connects to a web socked server and once function lighton() is called it send a web socket message to the server, however this is not working for some reason, any help

```
var cam_on;
var sock = null;
function connect()
{
    var url = "ws://" + location.host + ":8888/ws";
    var ws = new WebSocket(url);
    ws.onopen = function() 
    {

        $('#lighton').button("enable");
        $('#lightoff').button("enable");
        $('#stop').button("enable");

    };

    ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
    {
       alert(evt.data);
    };

    ws.onclose = function(evt) 
    { 
        alert("Connection close"); 
         $('#lighton').button("disable");
        $('#lightoff').button("disable");
        $('#stop').button("disable");

    };

};

function ws_send(message)
{

    if(ws)
        {
            ws.send(message);
       }    
};

function lighton() {
        alert("button pressed");
        ws_send("IR on");

};
```

update: solved, but the above is cleaner if it is possible

```
function init() {


//   connect();

   var url = "ws://" + location.host + ":8888/ws";
    var ws = new WebSocket(url);
    ws.onopen = function() 
    {

        $('#lighton').button("enable");
        $('#lightoff').button("enable");
        $('#stop').button("enable");

    };

    ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
    {
       alert(evt.data);
    };

    ws.onclose = function(evt) 
    { 
        alert("Connection close"); 
         $('#lighton').button("disable");
        $('#lightoff').button("disable");
        $('#stop').button("disable");

    };

    var lighton = document.getElementById("lighton");
    var lightoff = document.getElementById("lightoff");

    lighton.addEventListener("click", function(event)
    {
        ws.send("IR on");

    });

    lightoff.addEventListener("click", function(event)
    {
        ws.send("IR off");

    });


}
```

Comment: in ws_send you have if(ws){ws.send(message);}. Put an else clause so that you know you've got no ws. This is just for starts...

Comment: I have, but it is pointing to ws.send(message); this line does not work however

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow what you're coding, but one question stands out for sure: Who calls the function lighton? In the code you provided - noone. Perhaps you should provide more of your code...

Comment: I have updated my code, which now works, however the original code i had seems cleaner, I realised that calling the ws.send needs to be in the same functoin (i.e. init()) to work. any chance the functoin can be outside?!